# How to draw a jpanel/similar container in a double buffered jpanel?

Tags: java, swing

I have a jpanel where double buffering is implemented for flicker free graphics. Now I want to add a jpanel or similar container inside this double buffered jpanel. But the added jpanel starts to flicker as it is not graphics. I understood that only an image which contains graphics can be drawn in double buffering. But is there any other way to bypass it and find a solution.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.

Comment: Swing components are double buffered by default. You don't need to do anything special to take advantage of double buffering. If you are trying to implement your own double buffering then you are probably doing something wrong which is causing the problems.